# django_rq jobs are not added to the queue

Tags: django, docker, redis, django-rq

I am using:
  django-rq: 0.9.6
  rq_scheduler: 0.6.1

I am fairly new to docker and django_rq.

The issue that I am having is, my jobs are not executing or getting in the queue.

docker-compose.yml

```
redis:
    container_name: projapi-redis
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

rq:
    container_name: projapi-rq
    build: .
    command: python manage.py rqworker default
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    links:
      - redis

  rqscheduler:
    container_name: projapi-rqscheduler
    build: .
    command: python manage.py rqscheduler
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    links:
      - redis
```

settings.py

```
RQ_QUEUES = {
    'default': {
        'URL': 'redis://redis/0',
    }
}
```

In the python shell, I ran :`do_task.delay()` and the RQ Queues' finished jobs jumps up in number by a large amount. When I run: `scheduler.schedule(datetime.utcnow(), 'do_task', interval=20)`, I don't get any response.

tasks.py

```
from django_rq import job, get_scheduler
from datetime import datetime


scheduler = get_scheduler()


@job
def do_delay_task():
    return 'do_delay_task'


@job
def do_task():
    return 'do a task'


do_delay_task.delay()
scheduler.schedule(datetime.utcnow(), 'do_task', interval=2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is periodic task run, you forgot to run it:

```
scheduler.run()
```

also consider using of this module:
https://github.com/rq/rq-scheduler